Flutter Isar run build_runner build generate nothing
I'm new to flutter and Isar, I want to use Isar for the local DB for my app. When I try to use build_runner to generate the studylog.g.dart file, nothing was generated.
Here's my collection file
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';

part 'studylog.g.dart';

@collection
class Studylog{
  Id id = Isar.autoIncrement;

  late String videoID;
  late DateTime studydate;

}

@collection 
class Scores{
  Id id = Isar.autoIncrement;
  late int q1score;
  late int q1total;
  late int q2score;
  late int q2total;

  final studylog = IsarLink<Studylog>();

}

And after I run the fluttter pub run build_runner build, the output is:
Deprecated. Use `dart run` instead.
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 286ms
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph completed, took 76ms
[INFO] Checking for updates since last build completed, took 3.1s     
[INFO] Running build completed, took 10ms
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 55ms        
[INFO] Succeeded after 72ms with 0 outputs (0 actions)

When I run the  dart run build_runner doctor, I got the following output:
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 300ms
[WARNING] Builder isar_generator:isar_generator outputs .isar_generator.g.part  from .dart which is not specified in the `build.yaml`

I thought may be something goes wrong with the build.yaml.
A file called studylog.g.dart being generated

What's your file name? Is it -> "studylog.dart"

Yes the file name is "studylog.dart"

Nothing is wrong with your code. I just copy paste it and run command and it's working fine. command: flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs

First, create an empty file named studylog.g.dart next to your studylog.dart file. Then run the command:
dart run build_runner build

If it still doesn't work, delete the studylog.g.dart file and run the following commands in order:
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter pub outdated
dart run build_runner build


The second code works well for me. Thanks!

I had to add manually this dependency on the pubspec.yaml file: isar_generator: ^3.1.0+1, that works for me
